# Getting CORS error as per below in Microsoft Edge browser while calling azure search api from my custom application

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, microsoft-edge

I have a WebApp hosted in azure and Azure AD is used for authentication and i am am able to login to the application. But while calling a Azure Search Service api i am getting CORS  error as per below only in MS Edge browser in chrome and IE its working fine.

I have tracked the network and below is my observation:
When the Azure search service API is called its redirecting to Azure AD authentication and the CORS error is thrown but this rediection is not happening in chrome or IE so no issue in these browsers.

I have already configured my  site url to Azure AD  and i guess i can't modify the response header of the AD, then how to overcome this issue.

(Note:
1. I have added the CORS url in azure search as well as web app as well as while calling search api.
2. I am not getting this error in chrome or IE)

Error Message:
SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'https://mysiteurl.com' did not find 'https://mysiteurl.com' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at 'https://login.windows.net/ea80952e-a476-42d4-aaf4-5457852b0f7e/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmysiteurl.com%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=ca68e724-2c3d-4699-82bc-f8a56efa243a&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=8c756622bc8f4b02b03adcb41fbab33b_20190108150104&state=redir%3D%252Fapi%252Fsearch'.

My search method:

```js
return fetch("/api/search",
            {
                mode: "cors",
                headers: {
                    "api-key": searchState.config.queryKey,
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                    "access-control-allow-origin": "https://mysiteurl.com",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
                },
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(postBody)
            });
```

[See the below image where i have called the search API form behind]

Comment: did you actually check the response headers of that request ? you should mind the camel-case `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ,you are setting `access-control-allow-origin` but i dont think thats the issue

Comment: @johnSmith: Thanks for your response. CamelCasel i have checked it do not have any impact. I have checked  no CORS tag coming in response header form the auth url. As because the error is cmng from redirected Azure AD url not from the Azure Service api call

Comment: @johnSmith I have tracked the network and below is my observation: When the Azure search service API is called its redirecting to Azure AD authentication and the CORS error is thrown but this rediection is not happening in chrome or IE so no issue in these browsers

Comment: The path /api/search is not part of the Azure Search API. It looks to me like you’re calling your own API using CORS, not calling the Azure Search service directly. Can you confirm if this is the case?

Comment: @BruceJohnston. I am calling the azure search API form the code behind. See the code behind in the below image url 
https://imgur.com/gMbkqAV

Comment: Unless you’re somehow transpiling C# to JavaScript, that code is running in your application backend, not in the browser. This means that you don’t need to be passing the API key from the browser, nor do you need to configure the CORS options in Azure Search. Your CORS issues have nothing to do with Azure Search since you’re not actually calling your Azure Search service from the browser. While this won’t help with the CORS issue, I highly recommend using the .NET Azure Search SDK instead of calling the REST API directly, if at all possible.

Comment: @BruceJohnston Thanks for your comments. The problem is not calling. I am getting everything working even the response is coming in Chrome and in IE. The problem comes when i am using Microsoft edge browser, i am geting the above error. So my question is quite simple what is wrong with edge browser why its redirecting to azure AD url?

Comment: @QUDIRANSARI Sorry you're having trouble, but I don't know the answer to that. Hopefully someone familiar with the Edge implementation of CORS can answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and went through the painstaking process of finding a fix.

This is related to a bug in Edge's fetch implementation in versions 42.17434.  This is fixed in version 44.17763 (November 2018 and beyond).  You can find your Edge version by clicking the ellipsis in the upper right, clicking "settings", and scrolling to the bottom.

The core of this issue is that while most browser implementations send a default option of `credentials: 'same-origin'` when the credentials option is omitted, Edge does not.  You should be able to fix this for old Edge builds by adding the credentials same-origin option to your request:

```
return fetch("/api/search",
            {
                mode: "cors",
                credentials: "same-origin",
                headers: {
                    "api-key": searchState.config.queryKey,
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                    "access-control-allow-origin": "https://mysiteurl.com",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
                },
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(postBody)
            });
```

Related Edge issue tickets:

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19851173/
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7984069/